# pytest fixture which takes over error reporting

Tags: python, pytest

I'm writing a small fixture for implementing regression tests. The function under test does not contain any assert statements but produces output which is compared to a recorded output which is assumed to be correct.

This is a simplfied snippet to demonstrate what I'm doing:

```python
@pytest.yield_fixture()
def regtest(request):

    fp = cStringIO.StringIO()

    yield fp

    reset, full_path, id_ = _setup(request)
    if reset:
        _record_output(fp.getvalue(), full_path)
    else:
        failed = _compare_output(fp.getvalue(), full_path, request, id_)
        if failed:
            pytest.fail("regression test %s failed" % id_, pytrace=False)
```

In general my approach works works but I want to improve error reporting so that the fixture indicates the failure of a test and not the testing function itself: this implementation always prints a `.` because the testing function does not raise any exception, and then an extra `E` if `pytest.fail` is called in the last line.

So what I want is to supress the output of `.` triggered by the function under test and let my fixture code output the approriate character.

**Update**:
I was able to improve output, but it still I have to many "." in the output when the tests are running. It is uploaded at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-regtest
you can find the repository at https://sissource.ethz.ch/uweschmitt/pytest-regtest/tree/master

Sorry for posting links, but the files got a bit bigger now.

**Solution**:

I came up with a solution by implementing an hook which handles the regtest result in hook. The code is then (simplified):

```
@pytest.yield_fixture()
def regtest(request):
    fp = cStringIO.StringIO()
    yield fp

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_call(item):
    try:
        outcome = yield
    except Exception:
        raise
    else:
        # we only handle regtest fixture if no other other exception came up during testing:
        if outcome.excinfo is not None:
            return

        regtest = item.funcargs.get("regtest")
        if regtest is not None:
            _handle_regtest_result(regtest)
```

And `_handle_regtest_result` either stores the recorded values or does the appropriate checks. The plugin is now available at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-regtest

Comment: To be honest, the contents of your fixture look to me like they should be the contents of your test function. Are you still having problems with this? If so, can you put a more specific link to something in your repo?

Comment: Yes, using a fixture here is a "misuse". I find this approach simple from the users perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Your are mixing two things there: the fixture itself (setting up conditions for your test) and the expected behavior _compare_output(a, b). You are probably looking for something along the lines:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def file_fixture():
    fp = cStringIO.StringIO()
    return fp.getvalue()

@pytest.fixture()
def request_fixture(request, file_fixture):
    return _setup(request)

def test_regression(request_fixture, file_fixture):
    reset, full_path, id_ = request_fixture
    if reset:
        _record_output(file_fixture, full_path)
    else:
        failed = _compare_output(file_fixture, full_path, request, id_)
        assert failed is True, "regression test %s failed" % id_
```